# How to use custom Eclipse Che stacks on workstation host?

Tags: eclipse-che

I wonder what is a convenient way to use custom Eclipse Che stacks when running Che on a workstation.

I really like the concept of Eclipse Che: to have separate Che workspaces (Docker containers) for different development environments with corresponding tools installed. Workspaces are initialized from Che stacks. Stacks can be defined as Docker images or dynamically created using Dockerfiles or Docker composer files.

### What do I want to achieve:

- **[done]** have Eclipse Che installed on my workstation
- **[done]** ability to create my own custom stacks using Dockerfile syntax or local Docker images (images on my workstation not in Docker repository)
- **[done]** ability to painlessly reboot/shutdown my workstation
- **[done]** have a reasonable workspace startup time

### I have already tried:

**1. Define stack by recipe (Dockerfile)**

1. I wrote my custom Dockerfile for test purposes:

   ```
   FROM eclipse/stack-base:ubuntu

   RUN sudo apt-get update
   RUN sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

   RUN sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
   RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list

   RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

   RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential mongodb-org

   RUN sudo apt-get clean
   RUN sudo apt-get -y autoremove
   RUN sudo apt-get -y clean
   RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   ```

   It's based on `eclipse/stack-base:ubuntu` image as it is suggested in the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/devops/runtime-recipes/index.html#inherit-from-an-eclipse-che-base-image)
2. Then I created Che stack using *Build Stack From Recipe*.
3. After that I created a workspace based on this stack, it functions correctly.

This method has a significant drawback: *after a reboot of my workstation Che rebuilds workspace from Dockerfile!* As long as Dockerfile contains installation commands, the process takes considerable amount of time and obviously requires internet connection.

**2. Stack based on local Docker image**

1. I used my custom Dockerfile to build docker image locally:

   `sudo docker build -f custom.dockerfile -t my-custom-image .`
2. Then I created two Che stacks with the following configurations:

   ```
   {
     "scope": "general",
     "description": "Custom1",
     "tags": [],
     "workspaceConfig": {
       "environments": {
         "default": {
           "recipe": {
             "contentType": "text/x-dockerfile",
             "type": "dockerfile",
             "content": "FROM my-custom-image\n"
           },
           "machines": {
             "dev-machine": {
               "servers": {},
               "agents": [
                 "org.eclipse.che.ws-agent",
                 "org.eclipse.che.ssh",
                 "org.eclipse.che.terminal",
                 "org.eclipse.che.exec"
               ],
               "attributes": {
                 "memoryLimitBytes": "2147483648"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       },
       "defaultEnv": "default",
       "commands": [],
       "projects": [],
       "name": "default",
       "links": []
     },
     "components": [],
     "creator": "che",
     "name": "my-custom-1",
     "id": "stackx6hs410a9awhu299"
   }

   {
     "scope": "general",
     "description": "Custom2",
     "tags": [],
     "workspaceConfig": {
       "environments": {
         "default": {
           "recipe": {
             "contentType": "application/x-yaml",
             "type": "compose",
             "content": "services:\n dev-machine:\n  image: my-custom-image\n"
           },
           "machines": {
             "dev-machine": {
               "servers": {},
               "agents": [
                 "org.eclipse.che.exec",
                 "org.eclipse.che.terminal",
                 "org.eclipse.che.ws-agent",
                 "org.eclipse.che.ssh"
               ],
               "attributes": {
                 "memoryLimitBytes": "2147483648"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       },
       "defaultEnv": "default",
       "commands": [],
       "projects": [],
       "name": "custom",
       "links": []
     },
     "components": [],
     "creator": "che",
     "name": "my-custom-2",
     "id": "stack55s3tso56cljsf30"
   }
   ```
3. Workspaces based on these stacks fail to create with errors:

   `Could not start workspace my-custom-1. Reason: Start of environment 'default' failed. Error: Docker image build failed. Image id not found in build output.`

   `Could not start workspace my-custom-2. Reason: Start of environment 'default' failed. Error: Can't create machine from image. Cause: Error response from docker API, status: 404, message: repository my-node-mongo not found: does not exist or no pull access`

It looks like Che does not see Docker images on my workstation.

**So the question is: Is there any way to achieve my goals with Che? Or Che is not the right tool for me?**

### Update 1

**3. Setup local docker registry (https://docs.docker.com/registry/)**

1. Setup local docker registry: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/
2. Use Dockerfile to build a custom image

   `sudo docker build -f custom.dockerfile -t my-custom-image .`
3. Tag it and push it to local registry

   ```
   sudo docker tag my-custom-image localhost:5000/my-custom-image
   sudo docker push localhost:5000/my-custom-image
   ```
4. Create custom stack using image `localhost:5000/my-custom-image`

This approach works but has a definite **drawback: necessity to maintain docker registry**.

Anyway it works and I can tick two check-boxes in my whish-list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a local image, set `CHE_DOCKER_ALWAYS__PULL__IMAGE=false` in your che.env and restart Che.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this and write back. Are there any docs about this option? Will it prevent the Che server updates or only stack images updates?

Comment: Yep, setting `CHE_DOCKER_ALWAYS__PULL__IMAGE` to `false` indeed allows the use of local docker images for Che stacks and eliminates the need in local docker registry.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to run Che without any network connections (Update 2 in the question)?

Comment: Also how does `CHE_DOCKER_ALWAYS__PULL__IMAGE=false` differ from 'offline' mode (https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/getting-started/index.html#offline-installation)?

Comment: I'll edit the question and remove `offline` stuff from it to make this question more specific.

Comment: In officline mode, Che first downloads all infra images that it needs.