# how to persist a stack in eclipse che

Tags: stack, persist, eclipse-che

How do I create a stack in eclipse che so that it will persist? I have a LS-sidecar stack that I use, but every time I restart che, I need to re-make the stack. How do I make my stack permanent?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your own stack and create your workspace based on that stack. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793121/have-to-keep-reinstalling-python-modules-eclipse-che) how you can build your workspace from a stack based on Dockerfile recipe. Alternative way is to base your stack on a Docker Image (like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919884/how-to-use-custom-eclipse-che-stacks-on-workstation-host/47974917#47974917)) or on a [Docker Compose File](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). You can read [Eclipse Che documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/what-are-workspaces.html) (especially Workspace Administration) to see all options. Here is the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) where you can find help on building docker images.

There is also an extended [Red Hat Developer blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/che-custom-stacks/) about the cloud version of Eclipse Che (account required) that you may find useful as a step-by-step guide to building a stack from Docker Image, creating a workspace from it, importing a C++ github project and building it.